# How to prevent showing backing private fields of class properties in the Locals window?

Tags: vba, class

Although an experienced VBA programmer it is the first time that I make my own classes (objects). I am surprised to see that all properties are 'duplicated' in the Locals Window. A small example (break at 'End Sub'):

```
' Class module:
Private pName As String

Public Property Let Name(inValue As String)
    pName = inValue
End Property
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

' Normal module:
Sub Test()
    Dim objTest As cTest
    Set objTest = New cTest
    objTest.Name = "John Doe"
End Sub
```

Why are both `Name` and `pName` shown in the Locals Window? Can I in some way get rid of `pName`?

[image]

Comment: Its just trying to be helpful by showing you the value whilst you debug. pName is private and is not exposed across objTest to callers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As comments & answers already said, that's just the VBE being helpful.

However if you find it noisy to have the private fields and public members listed in the *locals* toolwindow, there's a way to nicely clean it up - here I put the `Test` procedure inside `ThisWorkbook`, and left the class named `Class1`:

[image: clean locals toolwindow]

So what's going on here? What's `this`?

Here's `Class1`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TClass1
    Name As String
    '...other members...
End Type

Private this As TClass1

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
    this.Name = value
End Property
```

The class only has 1 private field, a user-defined type value named `this`, which holds all the encapsulated data members.

As a result, the properties' underlying fields are effectively hidden, or rather, they're all regrouped under `this`, so you won't see the underlying field values unless you want to see them:

[image: locals toolwindow, 'this' field expanded]

And as an additional benefit, you don't need any pseudo-Hungarian prefixes anymore, the properties' implementations are crystal-clear, and best of all the properties have the exact same identifier name as their backing field.

Comment: Love this idea, time to rewrite all my classes to implement it.

Comment: @BSlater a side-effect of this is that you'll find it also makes serializing object state to a binary file, a walk in the park =)

Answer (score 6):

All the Inspection windows not only show the public interface of the objects to you, but also their private members. AFAIK there is nothing you can do about it.

Consider it a nice feature to get even more insights while debugging.

In my experience this is less of an issue in real world objects as they tend to have more fields and properties. Assuming a consistent naming (as your example shows), fields and properties are nicely grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

If you really dont want to see even Mathieu's `This` you could wrap it into a function. This is a bit more involved, and can be achieved using

1. a second class that stores the data in public variables. This will be marginally slower then Mattieu's implementation
2. a collection object that accesses the data using keys. This does not require additional clutter in the project exporer's 'class module' list but will be a little slower if you call the This repeatedly in fast sucession

An example for each is given below. If you break in the Class's Initialisation function, you can add `me` to the watch window and   only the `Name` property will be listed

Using 2 Objects example

insert a classmodule and name it: **InvisibleObjData**

```
Option Explicit
Public Name As String
Public plop

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Name = "new"
    plop = 0
End Sub
```

insert a classmodule and name it:  **InvisibleObj**

```
Option Explicit

Private Function This() As InvisibleObjData
    Static p As New InvisibleObjData 'static ensures the data object persists at successive calls
    Set This = p
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    This.Name = "invisible man":  Debug.Print Name
    Me.Name = "test":             Debug.Print Name
    This.plop = 111:              Debug.Print This.plop
End Sub

Property Let Name(aname As String): This.Name = aname:     End Property
Property Get Name() As String:           Name = This.Name: End Property

'_______________________________________________________________________________________
' in the immediate window type
'
'    set x=new invisibleObj
```

If you dont like splitting the class over two objects, a similar behaviour can be generated using a 'wrapped' collection object:

insert a classmodule and name it:  **InvisibleCol**

```
Option Explicit

Private Function This() As Collection
    Static p As New Collection
    'static ensures the collection object persists at successive calls
    'different instances will have different collections
    'note a better dictionary object may help
    Set This = p
End Function

Private Function add2this(s, v)
   'a better dictionary object instead of the collection would help...
    On Error Resume Next
    This.Remove s
    This.Add v, s
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    add2this "name", "invisible man":  Debug.Print Name
    Me.Name = "test":                       Debug.Print Name
    
    add2this "plop", 111
    Debug.Print This("plop")  ' use the key to access your data
    Debug.Print This!plop * 2 ' use of the BANG operator to reduce the number of dbl quotes
                              ' Note: This!plop is the same as This("plop")
End Sub

Property Let Name(aname As String): add2this "name", aname: End Property
Property Get Name() As String:            Name = This!Name: End Property


'_______________________________________________________________________________________
' in the immediate window type
'
'    set x=new invisibleCol
```